# BitBlt to invert colors using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, colors, bitblt

I am using BitBlt WinAPI to compose a bitmap using C++, and I was wondering what flags do I need to use to invert the colors in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you try?

[`BitBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- DSTINVERT Inverts the destination rectangle.
- PATINVERT Combines the colors of the brush currently selected in hdcDest, with the colors of the destination rectangle by using the Boolean XOR operator.
- SRCINVERT Combines the colors of the source and destination rectangles by using the Boolean XOR operator.

Comment: Yeah, those don't invert them. It seems like I'll have to convert it into bits and do it manually :(

Comment: I'd expect those to work, perhaps you tried it in a wrong way.

Comment: @ahmd0 How do you set the pixels of the bitmap that you pass to bitblt?

Comment: @Paolo: `CreateDIBSection` gets you bitmap handle + bits pointer.

Comment: @Paolo Brandoli I loaded them from an icon with GetIconInfo. And, no, I did try everything. So eventually I had to use GetDIBits to get the actual bits and do the work manually.

Comment: Now just to see if this could be done otherwise. Say, if each color pixel is represented by a 4-byte RGBA number, I need to do this: DWORD nCol = *pDesCol; *pDesCol = (nCol & 0xFF000000) | ((~nCol) & 0xFFFFFF);

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BitBlt()` with `NOTSRCCOPY`.

Here is your code:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), hdc, NULL, NULL, NOTSRCCOPY);
```